# Can't install extension on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, centos7, postgresql-extensions

I try to install semver on my Postgresql 12. I installed postgis successfully and used following command to install pg-semver ([semver](https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/doc/semver.html) extension) on my Centos 7 server:

```
yum install pg-semver
```

Then i ran

```
CREATE EXTENSION semver;
```

I got following error:

> couldn't open extension control file
>   /usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/semver.control : No such file or
>   directory

I copied all files from "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/" to "/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension". Now I'm getting following error:

> ERROR: ERROR: could not access file "semver": No such file or
>   directory

**UPDATE (28.02.2020):**

I removed pg-semver because it delivers for PSQL 9.2. I try to now build itself by using the documentation which developer provided.

I downloaded the semver extension from https://github.com/theory/pg-semver/archive/master.zip and then unzipped. After that I run following command:

```
make
```

and get:

> make: There is nothing to do for the "all" target.
>   then:

```
make install
```

and get:

> /bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c
>   -m 644 ./semver.control '/usr/share/pgsql/extension/' /bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644
>   ./sql/semver--0.20.0.sql ./sql/semver--unpackaged--0.2.1.sql
>   ./sql/semver--0.20.0--0.21.0.sql ./sql/semver--0.12.0--0.13.0.sql
>   ./sql/semver--0.3.0--0.4.0.sql ./sql/semver--0.16.0--0.17.0.sql
>   ./sql/semver--0.13.0--0.15.0.sql ./sql/semver--0.11.0--0.12.0.sql
>   ./sql/semver--0.2.4--0.3.0.sql ./sql/semver--0.2.1--0.2.4.sql
>   ./sql/semver--0.5.0--0.10.0.sql ./sql/semver--0.10.0--0.11.0.sql
>   ./sql/semver.sql ./sql/semver--0.17.0--0.20.0.sql
>   ./sql/semver--0.15.0--0.16.0.sql  '/usr/share/pgsql/extension/'
>   /bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c
>   -m 755  src/semver.so '/usr/lib64/pgsql/' /bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644
>   ./doc/semver.mmd '/usr/share/doc/pgsql/extension/'

then:

```
make installcheck
```

and get:

> ============== dropping database "contrib_regression" ============== DROP DATABASE
>   ============== creating database "contrib_regression" ============== CREATE DATABASE ALTER DATABASE
>   ============== installing plpgsql                     ============== CREATE LANGUAGE
>   ============== running regression test queries        ============== test base                     ... FAILED (test process exited with
>   exit code 3)
>
> ### --------------- 1 of 1 tests failed.
>
> The differences that caused some tests to fail can be viewed in the
>   file "/tmp/ttt/pg-semver-master/regression.diffs".  A copy of the test
>   summary that you see above is saved in the file
>   "/tmp/ttt/pg-semver-master/regression.out".
>
> make: *** [installcheck] Error 1

the content of regression.out:

> ...... ! ok 278 - minor version check ! ok 279 - Function
>   get_semver_patch() should exist ! ok 280 - semver ! ok 281 - Function
>   get_semver_patch() should return integer ! ok 282 - patch version
>   check ! ok 283 - Function get_semver_prerelease() should exist ! ok
>   284 - semver ! ok 285 - Function get_semver_prerelease() should return
>   text ! ok 286 - prerelease label check ! ok 287 - 1.0.0 should be in
>   range [1.0.0, 2.0.0] ! ok 288 - 1.0.0 should not be in range [1.0.1,
>   2.0.0] ! ok 289 - 2.0.0 should not be in range [1.0.1, 2.0.0) ! ok 290 - 1.9999.9999 should be in range [1.0.1, 2.0.0) ! ok 291 - 1000.0.0 should be in range [1.0.0,) ! ok 292 - Should be able to work with
>   arrays of semverranges
>   --- 1,2 ----   \set ECHO none ! psql:sql/semver.sql:30: ERROR:  could not access file "semver": No such file or directory

There is no semver.so in /usr/pgsql-12/lib/, there is a semver.so in /usr/lib64/pgsql/ but it's also for version 9.2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are unable to install `semver` is twofold:

You are getting the error `could not access file "semver": No such file or directory` because you didn't copy `/usr/lib64/pgsql/semver.so` to `/usr/pgsql-12/lib`.  However, you can't simply copy that over because of this following second reason:

`yum install pg-semver` will install `semver` from the EPEL library, which is the pre-packaged PostgreSQL version 9.2 that is shipped with CentOS 7.  You installed PostgreSQL version 12 (either by compiling it yourself or downloading the PGDG repo and installing the `postgresql12` package).  The `semver.so` file that is shipped with the EPEL repo is not compatible, as it was compiled against PostgreSQL version 9.2, not version 12.  If you attempt to load the EPEL `semver.so` into your v.12 database, you will see:

```
postgres=# create extension semver;
ERROR:  incompatible library "/usr/pgsql-12/lib/semver.so": version mismatch
DETAIL:  Server is version 12, library is version 9.2.
```

Therefore, the only way for you to install `semver` is by following the compilation steps [detailed in the documentation](https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/):

```
make
make install
make installcheck
psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION semver;"
```

If you have not done so already (and you installed postgresql 12 via PGDG RPM), you will need to do the following in order to download and compile:

```
yum -y install postgresql12-devel
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

You may also run into issues with compilation, like: `clang: error: unknown argument: '-flto=thin'` because the PGDG RPM was compiled with `clang` -- you can bypass that by doing:

```
with_llvm=no make -e
with_llvm=no make -e install
with_llvm=no make -e installcheck
psql -c "create extension semver"
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Oh now i understand ht incompatible problem. But when i run "make installcheck" i get "! psql:sql/semver.sql:30: ERROR:  could not access file "semver": No such file or directory"....

Comment: mmm, seems like your paste got mangled--can you update your original post with the error message (and more context, like the command(s) that you issued)?  Also, I updated my post re `clang` errors you might see

Comment: ah ok i see.  Odd -- you may want to `make clean` and then `make` again.  But based on your output you may not need to do that.  I see `/bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 755 src/semver.so '/usr/lib64/pgsql/'` -- this means that /usr/lib64/pgsql/semserver.so` *should* be for your `postgresql12` version (unless you have some collision from some other Postgres version).  Just copy that `semver.so` to `/usr/pgsql-12/lib` and try `make installcheck` again

Comment: I made also make clean and then started again and copied the semver.so, but i still get "! DETAIL:  Server is version 12, library is version 9.2." error

Comment: If that's the case, it seems you still have Postgres 9.2 installed on your system (i.e., you probably have both v. 9.2 and v. 12 installed) -- you can verify this by looking at the output of `rpm -aq | grep postgres` and `pg_config` -- be sure to remove all traces of v. 9.2 and try your `make` again

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide to install semver:

https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/

Comment: I already did it. When i download zhe semver zip file and unzip it, i run make install but i'm getting error "make: *** No rule to create "install". Enough." (translated)

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to resolve “semver” extension issue of postgresql(MACOS/LINUX)**

- Download the zipped extension file from here: https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/
- Unzip the file
- Run these commands one by one from the command line (macOS/linux):
  `cd <unzipped_folder> (ex: semver-0.32.1)` 
  `make` 
  `make install` 
  `make installcheck`  

  FOR MAC, POSTGRES V14.8, FOR Linux provide the pg_config file location
  `env PG_CONFIG=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.8_2/bin/pg_config && make installcheck && make install`
     

  any superuser of postgres db, in my case: postgres
  `make install check PGUSER=<super_user>`
- Connect to postgres from command line: `psql postgres`
- Run this in postgres console: `CREATE EXTENSION semver;`  

   Hope it will work fine.

   For more see this: [https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/](https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/%E2%80%A8)