# ERROR: incompatible library while creating extension in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I use Centos 7 and Postgresql 12. I installed already PostGIS and created successfully its extension. I'm now tring to install semver extension with **create extension semver** and get following error:

> ERROR: incompatible library »/usr/pgsql-12/lib/semver.so«: version
>   does not match

According to developer this version should work with my Postgresql 12. Why am i getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install `semver`? It sounds like your `.so` file was built against an earlier version of Postgres.

Comment: because i want to compare software versions in my table. But it's the last version...

Comment: But where did you get the `.so` file? Even for the same version of `semver` (e.g. `0.21.0`), you need different `.so` files for Postgres 12, 11, 10, etc., and it sounds like yours was not built for Postgres 12.

Comment: i installed it via yum install pg-semver and it installs "pg-semver-0.5.0-2.el7.x86_64"

Comment: i had some troubles while installing semver, because yum puts the .so file in a different lib folder, where postgresql couldn't find it. that's why i had to manually move the semver.so file to postgresql's lib folder for extensions. (see the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395560/cant-install-extension-on-postgresql )

Answer (score 1):

An extension's `.so` binaries are specific to a major release of Postgres.

If you're installing the extension through `yum`, there would typically be a different package for each Postgres version. For example, if you installed Postgres 12 using the `postgresql12-server` package, then you would install PostGIS 3.0 using the `postgis30_12` package.

If the package name is just `pg-semver`, without a Postgres version number, then it's probably intended for your distribution's default `postgresql-server` package. [In CentOS 7](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/), this appears to be Postgres 9.2, so these files won't work on a Postgres 12 server.

If you can't find a PG12-specific package, you'll need to build it yourself, using the instructions [here](https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/).